# Issue with subclass and superclass using same named properties

Tags: objective-c

This is something very fascinating I observed today. Maybe that's how Objective-C works but I didn't know about this. See the following code below:

```
// ATableViewController.h
@interface ATableViewController : UITableViewController
@end

// ATableViewController.m
@interface ATableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) int volly;
@end

@implementation ATableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.volly = 5;
}
@end

// BTableViewController.h
@interface BTableViewController : ATableViewController
@end

// BTableViewController.m
@interface BTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) int volly;
@end

@implementation BTableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%d", self.volly); // returns 5
}
@end
```

I am not sure why the above is valid. I do understand that I passed a message 'volly' to the object 'self' which in turn probably looked at the value from the super class but shouldn't these be initialized? Some explanation would be of great help. Thanks.

EDIT: This is a big problem IMO though. Considering I don't know any of the private properties defined in the super class, my own set of values might end up being different.

For example, a developer may set a boolean flag `hasAppeared` in `viewDidAppear:`. This same value will be set for my subclass instance in `viewDidAppear:` after the `[super viewDidAppear:]` call. This will be before I actually get to set it myself.

Currently, the solution is I know exactly the variable used by the super class and I can avoid using the same value but I deem this to be a larger issue than it seems.

EDIT 2: The behavior is consistent with binaries (with only headers) as well as with frameworks where implementation is available.

Comment: I'm interested in that answer too, please notify with a comment if someones says something interesting :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 'Why the above is valid?' + 'How to not get this behavior?' + 'How to avoid this given a developer might not know private properties of a superclass?'

Comment: By definition subclassing involves inheritance and that is exactly what happens in your code above. If you don't want the value of self.volly to be set to 5 simply don't set it in the superclass.

Comment: Is your issue with the fact that `self.volie` is a private property and you can still modify it in your subclass? If that's the case there is no way to truly declare a private property in Objective-C. BUT, if you declare the superclass property in its implementation file (.m) and subclass it using a separate implementation file then you won't be able to access the property in the subclass.

Comment: I am not sure you are getting it. I am not referring to myself setting these values but pointing to the fact that I might end up using the same property names as used by a super class (a superclass developed by somebody; e.g. a framework for which only headers are available). These values defined in the superclass might interfere in my own subclass. That is the real issue.

Comment: I understand that there is no concept of a private property in Objective-C. It's just that these unknown properties in a superclass interfere with the subclass if they happen to have the same name. This is a big issue.

Comment: Consider the code here — https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-iOS/blob/master/Code/Controllers/ATLConversationListViewController.m. If I were to use the same `hasAppeared` boolean type in my own subclass, then it wouldn't work; as every time the superclass will be overwriting it.

Comment: If you want volley to be private declare it as an iVar: `@implementation ATableViewController {int volley;}`. Alternatively convert to Swift and declare it private using the `private` declaration.

Comment: I still don't see what the issue is. You can either set your hasAppeared value after calling super or (where not required) not call super at all.

Comment: `hasAppeared` is already set when I try to use it `viewDidAppear` because of a call to super. And I cannot afford to not call super here.

Comment: I am not sure why you are not seeing this as an issue. This is very unsafe. Currently I have the source for `ATLParticipantTableViewController` so I can just simply change the name from `hasAppeared` to `appeared` and everything will go away. But there could be unknown properties which I might be fiddling with.

As explained, the properties are already set before I can manually set them.

Comment: @p0lAris What if the parent and subclass are in different frameworks in your project?

Comment: Currently, that is the setup. I am using an external framework and creating a subclass (as advised in the framework guidelines). The framework is installed via cocoapods so I am not sure exactly what would happen if the framework was a compiled binary with only public headers for usage. I am not sure if this is what you are asking, though.

Comment: No, I was asking about this setup exactly.  Would be interesting to also try with compiled library with only public headers.  Also, what happens if the subclass tries to declare the property as a different type?  Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: I am tending to believe that the behavior will be consistent as there is no concept of truly private in Objective-C.

Comment: Apologies I can finally see what you mean now and you are right. With `public` properties you at least get a compiler warning when they are being overridden by the subclass but that is not the case with properties declared `privately`.

Comment: Thanks. And no issues at all. I deem this behavior to be extremely unsafe. I am currently testing a custom binary to see if this is only with situations where source is available or with binaries as well.

Comment: @nhgrif Same behavior for binaries as well.

Comment: This is a potential problem unless you realize that Objective-C property model is not really about inheritance, but about something often called *monkey patching*. Most classes are designed to be "final" and do not bother using _x instead of [self x], opening an ability to patch the behavior without complex inheritance contracts. If the base class was designed to be really opaque-base *and* it uses property accessors for it's own very private accounting, that design is just broken. Ivars on itself work as expected – each level has it's own distinct set of privates.

Comment: tl;dr Class hierarchy contracts are subject to careful design, and that is *not* Objective-C-specific.

Comment: Are you suggesting that one must not use properties? Or to not use property accessors with properties (as one can only observer changes by using accessors)?

Comment: Framework developer who proposes subclassing and overriding properties must be consistent with accessing them *only* through accessors or *only* directly through an ivar. Otherwise, subclasser would be in trouble, just as you noticed. There is nothing to suggest and since you see all the implications, there is actually no question nor answer. IMO, Apple pushed it's "declare a private category with properties for every ivar" paradigm too far in theoretical sense, but that's okay in virtually all practical cases, as/thus all objc classes are final by design, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: That's also why they often have "subclassing notes" section in their docs.

Comment: That is very close to what I was waiting for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this without reading all of the comments.

There is no issue here. Both `AViewController` (`AVC`) and `BViewController` (`BVC`) each have their own private property named `volly`.

You created an instance of `BVC`. It can't see the `volly` property from its parent class (because it is private), just its own.

Now the fun begins.

The `viewDidLoad` method from `BVC` is called. It in turn calls `[super viewDidLoad];` which of course calls the `viewDidLoad` from the `AVC` class. That method, in turn, calls `self.volly = 5;`.

The confusion seems to be with this line. Remember, `self.volly = 5;` is really a call to:

```
[self setVolly:5];
```

Both `AVC` and `BVC` have the (synthesized) `setVolly:` method. Since `self` is a pointer to an instance of a `BVC` object, the call to `[self setVolly:5];` results in a call to the `setVolly:` method in the `BVC` class despite being called from a method in the `AVC` class.

Here's the code with some annotations:

The 'BVC' class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // calls the method in `AVC`
    NSLog(@"%d", self.volly); // returns 5
}
```

The 'AVC' class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // calls the UITableViewController method
    // The following is really [self setVolly:5];
    // Since "self" is a "BVC", the private "volly" property of
    // the "BVC" class is actually set here.
    // The private "volly" property of the "AVC" class will still be
    // 0 after this call.
    self.volly = 5;
}
```

In the end, the subclass is *not* using the private property of the parent class. The original premise in the question's title is incorrect.

Comment: I agree and I comprehend. From the description in the OP as well as the comments, we have discerned that this is how Objective-C works and this is how it should be. But my concern is mainly about the implication of the above rather than 'how it is done'.

Comment: I will try and review the title accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: What is the implication you are concerned with here?

Comment: Please don't mind but if you could read the comments, that'd be great. If it's confusing, I am happy to try again. :)

Comment: So... basically, the `_volly` (the actual instance variable) is actually different between the two... but any call to `setVolly:` is going to set both instance variables?

Comment: @nhgrif Each class has it's own `_volly` ivar. But the provided code results in the `_volly` ivar of the `AVC` class never being set. It's still `0` when the `_volly` variable of the `BVC` class is set to `5`.

Comment: Oh right, this makes sense.  The subclass hides away the parent class's `_volly` completely.

Comment: @p0lAris OK, your concern is that the parent class and the subclass end up changing the same variable instead of each changing different variables with two different purposes. That is a potential issue.

Comment: Yes sir. But majorly, that the parent class is unintentionally *potentially* messing with the values in the subclass.

Comment: Right. We are all in agreement with the what the potential problem is. So is your question how to deal with this properly or how to avoid it?

Comment: Both. How to avoid this problem? Example, the subclass should be able to create any custom properties and use them without any issue. How to deal with it? Considering that the problem exists (as in my case), how we deal with it? Currently, it was easy — just change the variable name. What would be expected in the future?